# Calculate Length of String with Escape Characters/Special Chars

Tags: c#

In c# when getting the lenght of a string it doesn't include special characters like new line or a unicode character so the strings `It's nice to meet you` and `It\'s nice to meet you` are the same length eventhough one is 1 character longer.

Is there are way to get the number of characters incuding the slash?

Currently my only solution is to replace the special characters I know I'm using with there equivent. for example do this:

```cs
"line 1\nline2".Replace("\n", "\\n").Length
```

Comment: That's just not accurate.  Of course it includes the special characters.  Can you provide some code to show us exactly what you mean?

Comment: You're confusing the C# string expression (representation) in source code with its run time value. Escape sequences only exist in source code. They are not part of the string itself.

Comment: ^ Good point.  You need to make your question clearer.  We shouldn't have to edit your question just to see what the actual characters are in your two string examples.

Comment: I edited OP's question because the formatting caused it to not show the alleged problem right. @rory.ap

Comment: If you need the length of the in-source expression at run time, you'll need to convert it to a C# string expression. But there are multiple ways to represent certain characters. For example, `\u0022` and `\"` are the same character. You'll never get how it was in source code unless you *look at the source code*. Why do you want this? Are you generating source code, and doing so into a buffer where you need to know how much to allocate? Otherwise, this seems like an X/Y problem.

Comment: In c# `"\n"` is how you write the new line character inside a string. If you want to literally read `\n` then you should either escape the \ inside the string or just declare the string as non-escapable adding an `@` before the string: `@"Line1\nline2".Length`.

Comment: @mdereflection asked why I wanted to do this. This is the scenario. I have code that is in my database generated, by another program,  I have to put those strings in a JSON object that is then sent to a third-party system to be processed. Their code does not count the '\n' as one character but 2 and without intervention, as shown in my ineloquent solution, I end up receiving errors that I am over the field size. The problem with my way is that I have to know all the escaped values that I need to replace in order for it to show the correct size.

Comment: Also thanks to @Cleptus for making my question more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of the string using @ at the front

```
string s = @"line 1\nline2";
```

`@` will tell it to treat it as a verbatim string literal, calling s.count() will have the correct count.

Comment: Thanks, Justin but I don't have the ability to control the creation of the string. I tried in my post to have this be generic and while your solution works with my simple sample code it does not work with my actual code.